# not able to find lat/long for an address

Tags: javascript, geolocation, geocode, google-geocoder

I have a javascript code, and want to find latitude/longitude for an address entered by a user.

I am using following javascript code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var address = document.getElementById("address").value;
var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
  var location = results[0].geometry.location;
  alert(location.lat() + '' + location.lng());
});
</script>
```

But the above code is not working. Can anybody suggest what could be the problem. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Running that code on its own works fine. It is probably worth checking your address value is being picked up correctly, and that there are no other javascript errors on the page.